# DOM4J/XPATH Parsing of document

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

```
Node existingUserNode = loginDoc.selectSingleNode("/returningUser");
String username = existingUserNode.selectSingleNode("/username").getText();
String password = existingUserNode.selectSingleNode("/password").getText();
```

for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><returningUser><username>user</username><password>password</password></returningUser>
```

returns null.

I don't think my xpath is wrong? Or am I using the wrong method?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be ./username and ./password... above I am looking one level too high by referencing the root

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Node existingUserNode = loginDoc.selectSingleNode("/returningUser");
String username = existingUserNode.selectSingleNode("/username").getNodeValue();
String password = existingUserNode.selectSingleNode("/password").getNodeValue();
```